# Почему вместо вывода в консоль ссылки, хранящейся в переменной, выводится содержимое первой ячейки массива?

Tags: java, printf

Объясните механику в данном случае, пожалуйста.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list;
        list = new String[10];
        list[1] = "someString";
        System.out.printf("list = %s", list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод `java.io.PrintStream#printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`. Последний аргумент - это `varargs`. Передаваемый Вами массив интерпретируется не как один объект, а как множество объектов, содержащихся в нем. Т.е. как будто бы Вы вызвали метод следующим образом - `System.out.printf("list = %s", list[0], list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6],list[7],list[8],list[9]);`.

Вы можете привести Ваш массив к классу `Object`:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list;
        list = new String[10];
        list[1] = "someString";
        System.out.printf("list = %s", (Object)list);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
list = [Ljava.lang.String;@4de8b406
```

Comment: Александр, спасибо! :)